# Error = mod: nonconformant arguments (op1 is 3x1, op2 is 2x1) in Octave

Tags: image, compression, octave

In octave I was trying to compress image by using "blockproc" function. I came to an error and I am unable to resolve it. Here is my code:

```
f1= @(block_struct) dct2(block_struct.data);
f2= @(block_struct) idct2(block_struct.data);
A = imread("group.jpg");
imwrite(A, "new.jpg");
%Im = rgb2gray(A);
%figure, imshow(A);
J= blockproc (A, [8 8],f1);
depth= find(abs(J) <150);
J(depth)= zeros(size(depth));
K= blockproc(J, [8 8], f2)/255;
figure, imshow(K);
imwrite(K, "new1.jpg");
compression_ratio= numel(J)/numel(depth)
```

[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYl1f.png)

Comment: Can you please give us the size of each matrix in the code above? Also, which of the two blockproc instances is giving this error?

Comment: First blockproc is giving an error and size of "A" matrix is 445x446x3.

Comment: I am doing my assignment related to Octave. My assignment's statement is as follow:
You are required to take at least five images with different resolution and use SVD for image compression. For each image,
   - How many modes do you need for compressed color (RGB) image to look good?
   - How much more efficient are your nice compressed images in terms of storage 
     space?

I want you guys please help me to complete this assignment. I have attached my code. Please make my code good according to question statement.